# Importing a source code repository from AWS Code Commit into Github

Tags: github, aws-codecommit

We are using AWS Code Commit for source code and considering moving to Github in the near future. What is the easiest way to accomplish this ? I have seen a lot of articles about importing a Github project into AWS Code commit but not the other way around.

Comment: Why would it be different going the other way, or any other Git migration? Add a remote for GitHub and push your code.

Comment: Thanks Chris. i am new to Github. So are there any pointers/articles explaining how to add a remote for Github ?

Comment: Yes, [there are lots](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=add+second+git+remote). We're not here to find things for you. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Try something. If you get stuck, search. If you don't find anything, come back and ask a _concrete_ question.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response. Not sure if there is a need to be rude here. If you don't want to respond please don't. I will try out a few things with GitHub  and come back with questions as needed.

Comment: I didn't intend to be rude. I was merely pointing out that certain things are on-topic here and others are off-topic. Since you brought it up, reading and following a community's guidelines might be considered a polite thing to do. We also have a [tour] that you don't appear to have taken (doing so earns you a bronze badge).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to clone your code commit repo and push it to your GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very fair question and none of the comments have addressed it. Though it is trivial to [migrate the git repo](https://manumagalhaes.medium.com/how-to-migrate-codecommit-to-github-and-keep-your-amplify-pipeline-da8d323ef36d), that is not a full clone of all meta data related to it. This is roughly:

1. `git clone --mirror <source repo>`
2. Create new, empty repo in a GitHub org you can write to
3. `git add remote target <dest repo>`
4. `git push --mirror target`

What gets missed doing git migrations like this is things such as users/groups permissions, pull requests, secrets, and probably other things I've forgotten. This meta data is not stored in the git repo and needs to be re-implemented on the GitHub side. As there are usually APIs to the Git systems, migration scripts can be written and some are [written by GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/source-code-migration-tools), some by individuals (though I struggled to find any active examples).

I too have searched extensively for a migration tool that actually gets all the data for an AWS CodeCommit repo and reproduces it as a GitHub repo.

It looks like I should be able to write a script that uses the [AWS REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-view-pull-request.html#how-to-view-pull-request-cli) to get the data and then write it to the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#create-a-pull-request). I was hoping this code already existed and I would save a bunch of time writing and debugging it.